# How to authenticate ladp user using spring-data-ldap?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-security-ldap

I was able to create user using spring data ldap module, when I try to authenticate with userid and password it is giving error. My guess was when user is created ladp is performing some encryption on password and saving it it the ldap tree. How can I know which encryption ldao is using. I have seen some exapmles how user is authenticated using spring-security-ldap, I need help with spring-data-ldap.
Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In which case do you want to manually authenticate an user? If you got spring security's configuration right, it would manage all the work for you. Can you also post the error you're getting?

Comment: I just followed this article from github, I had the same exact configuration mentioned here. https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-ldap

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting? I will then try to replicate your scenario.

Comment: [LDAP: error code 49 - NDS error: failed authentication (-669)]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - NDS error: failed authentication (-669)]",

Comment: I think I need to add sone authentication provider, (like ldapauthenticationprovider) to authenticate the user. Not sure..

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is come code I have from work, that provides configuration on spring security using LDAP as an authentication provider. Maybe it will give you some insight on how to make it work. I added some comments to describe some key points of the implementation. This is code from my config class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()                    
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login") // defines the login page
                .loginProcessingUrl("/userAuth") // defines the endpoint which the post with the login form must be sent to.
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()); // defines LDAP as your authentication provider.
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(DOMAIN, URL, ROOT_DN); // instantiate and connects to your LDAP provider. DOMAIN, URL and ROOT_DN must be info you have from your LDAP.
        authenticationProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        authenticationProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

        return authenticationProvider;
}
```

With an implementation like this, any login form coming from `/login` and being posted to `/userAuth` will be authenticated on your LDAP server. Therefore, you should not be worried about encrypting passwords or any of that. LDAP authentication provider gets you covered.